# Can you Have multiple unit test files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have two unit test files in Visual Studio, for example `test1.cs` and `test2.cs`... When I select run all tests, it only runs the test from `test1.cs`. How can I make visual studio run tests from both `test1.cs` and `test2.cs`?

Additional information: If I select a test method from `test2.cs`, the output will tell me "No tests found to run."

(test2.cs ==  ADPReportClassTest.cs)

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
namespace EmployeeRefreshTest.tests
{
    [TestClass]
    class ADPReportClassTest
    {
        TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

        [TestMethod]
        [DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Server=Localhost;Database=Test_Employee_Refresh;Integrated Security=Yes", "ADPREPORTCLASS_Tuples", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
        public void Checkconstructor()
        {
            string filename = TestContext.DataRow["TestFileName"].ToString();
            Assert.AreEqual(filename, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing your `test2` isn't set up correctly.  Show us how its set up.

Comment: @Amy here is what the file looks like

Comment: Is the `Build Action` set to `Compile`?

Comment: @GiladGreen Visual Studio's unit testing

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Right click the file > Properties and "Build Action"

Comment: In source explorer click on the file then look in the properties pane.  You will see an option that says `Build Action` and it should be set to `Compile`

Comment: Yes it is set to compile

Comment: How are you running the tests?  and are you getting and compiler errors?

Comment: the build succeeds

Comment: @FrancoPettigrosso. Because all tests need to be `public` in order for the test runner to be able to see it. Unless that was just a typo in the example you posted

Comment: Nkosi wins :) ...

Comment: @Nkosi I see it as our duty as SO users to hoard as many useless internet points as possible.  So have another.

Comment: @Amy you had me worried there. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the test runner to see all relevant members to be used in testing they must be `public`. So that would include all test classes, their test methods and any contexts that are needed for data sources.

Update the test accordingly

```
[TestClass]
public class ADPReportClassTest //<-- public
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; } //<-- public

    [TestMethod]
    [DataSource("System.Data.SqlClient", "Server=Localhost;Database=Test_Employee_Refresh;Integrated Security=Yes", "ADPREPORTCLASS_Tuples", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    public void Checkconstructor() //<-- public
    {
        string filename = TestContext.DataRow["TestFileName"].ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual(filename, filename);
    }
}
```